# Graph construction in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to draw a graph given below  in matlab

`f(v)=  (Sinx)v^2 + (cosx)v +2x`  where x ranges between 0 to 10 and after putting x in f(v) and then solve for v . We get two zeroes. In my problem, I have to draw a graph in Matlab between x and one of the zeroes of f(v). I need a MATLAB program for this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can draw the graph by using "plot" function.

If you wonder how to set the range of your function, Enter the "help plot" and read.

Also, you should assign the your function with "inline" function.
`f(v)=  (Sinx)v^2 + (cosx)v +2x`  is wrong.
you should type `f(v)=  (Sin(x))*v^2 + (cos(x))*v +2*x`.

Thx.

Comment: HMan@, yeah I want to write a program to plot one of roots of given polynomial versus x.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but you should try to do it yourself. Show us what problem you encounter and why you are not able to solve it yourself. And ask a question. But dont just say: I need a program.

Comment: This is not assignment solving community. Do not expect somebody to solve your homework without showing any effort!

Comment: I fully agree with two guys above. So, just try it. You can. easily get answer by using “help” functions. It has details in MATLAB.